# knockout nested foreach binding is not working

Tags: knockout.js

I have html as:  [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wnzrr/1/)

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: Items">
    <li data-bind="click: setTextColor, text: 'Color: ' + color"></li>
     <ul data-bind="foreach:add">
         <li data-bind="text:test"></li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

and JS as below:

```
var Item = function(color) {
    var self = this;
    self.color = String(color);
    self.setTextColor = function(item, event) {
        console.log(item.color);
        $(event.target).css('color', color);
    };
},
     add = function (test){
        
        this.test = String (test);
};
ko.applyBindings(new function() {
    this.Items = ko.observableArray([
        {new Item('red'),ko.observableArray(new add('colore'),new add('is'),new add('red'))},
        {new Item('blue'),ko.observableArray(new add('colore'),new add('is'),new add('blue'))},
        {new Item('green'), ko.observableArray(new add('colore'),new add('is'),new add('green'))}
    ]);
}());
```

But it is not populating the data.
Can any one tell me what is the problem!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it something like this:

```
var Item = function(color, a) {
    var self = this;
    self.color = String(color);
    self.setTextColor = function(item, event) {
        console.log(item.color);
        $(event.target).css('color', color);
    };
    self.add = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(a, function(item) { return new add(item); }));
},
add = function (test){
    this.test = String (test);
};
ko.applyBindings(new function() {
    this.Items = ko.observableArray([
        new Item('red',['colore','is','red']),
        new Item('blue',['colore','is','blue']),
        new Item('green', ['colore','is','green'])
    ]);
}());
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ENQzc/

Comment: it works great. But i am try to understand this line==
ko.utils.arrayMap(a, function(item) { return new add(item);

Comment: ko.utils.arrayMap, which executes a function for each item in an array and pushes the result of the function to a new array that is returned.

Comment: The utility functions for Knockout are described here: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html

Comment: additional question. inside setTextColor function what if i want to know what are values are (like we have 'colore','is','red'). So we need to do with knockout or jquery and how?

Comment: item.add() will return an array, so item.add().length would be 3, and item.add()[2] would be 'red' (or whatever).

Answer (score 0):

Firebug or Chrome console maybe?

> ```
> SyntaxError: missing : after property id
> [Stanna vid fel]  
>
> {new Item('red'),ko.observableArray(new add('colore'),new add('is
>
> /Wnzrr/1/show/ (line 49, col 14)
> ```

Your array definition at bottom is really strange, what are you trying todo?